# Name of internal hard drive keeps changing

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I have a computer running as a server for Plex media among other things. I store my media on an internal hard drive, and Ubuntu is installed on an SSD.

For some reason the name that Ubuntu assigns to the hard drive keeps changing, and I'm not sure why. Initially it was PLEX, then it changed it to PLEX1, and now it has changed to PLEX2. I wouldn't care too much, except it's screwing up my volume mappings for Docker containers.

Answer (score 5):

Add a line to `/etc/fstab` to assign a mount point for the drive on every boot by following the below instructions from [How to label disk partition in Linux](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-label-hard-drive-partition-under-linux) .

---

#### Label disk partition examples

To see the device path of all your hard disk partitions, you can use the `fdisk` command.

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

The `blkid` command can be used to show the current partition label (if any) and UUID of the disk partition. Simply specify the device path of the partition you wish to see.

```
$ blkid /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1: UUID="a80ad9d4-90ff-4903-b34d-ca70d82762ed" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="75efe5f1-05"
```

One way to add a label to a disk partition is with the `e2label` command. Use the below syntax to add a label to any disk partition of your choosing.

```
sudo e2label /dev/sda1 "MY_BACKUP"
```

Another way to add a label is with the `tune2fs` command. The following syntax would be used to add a label to the `/dev/sda1` partition.

```
sudo tune2fs -L "MY_BACKUP" /dev/sda1
```

The `e2label` and `tune2fs` commands will work fine for ext2, ext3 and ext4 formatted partitions. To label a partition that's been formatted as ntfs, you will need to use `ntfslabel` instead.

```
sudo ntfslabel /dev/sda1 NTFS_DRIVE
```

To label a swap partition, you can use the `mkswap` command with the following syntax.

```
sudo mkswap -L SWAP_PARTITION /dev/sda1
```

#### Mount hard drive partitions by label

Now we are able to refer to `/dev/sda1` as MY_BACKUP, after adding that label to the disk partition in an earlier step. To do so edit the `/etc/fstab` file and add the following line:

```
LABEL=MY_BACKUP /mount/point           ext4    defaults        0       2
```